# hudson clearcase plugin

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson, clearcase

I am using hudson clearcase plugin( with maven), i have gone through document and it says download hudson clearcase plugin from link here: [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clearcase+Plugin).

```
  1) where i need to keep this plugin? ie which location?
  2) Is hudson and jenkins are same?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for how to install the plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins

You can treat Hudson and Jenkins as same, for now at least, but here is info on what are Hudson and Jenkins - http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/01/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Note: copying the [latest `clearcase.hpi`](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/clearcase.hpi) to your `plugin` directory of Jenkins means restarting Jenkins itself (or its container like Tomcat).
That can be an issue when you have several Jenkins within one container: all of them are stopped/restarted.

On the Jenkins/Hudson issue, you can also look at the blog post "[Hudson and Jenkins: Two Months Later](http://daniel.gredler.net/2011/04/04/hudson-and-jenkins-two-months-later/)"